# konsole color schemes

Tags: terminal, colors

I've noticed that KDE's konsole terminal program uses different colors depending on what is in the file system, such as a directory, a compressed file, a socket, a shared directory, et cetera.

I looked through the konsole documentation (konsole handbook) but I did not see anywhere that described what each number corresponds to for both regular and intense settings. Any ideas where I might be able to find such a reference?

Comment: As ADwarf explains, this has nothing to do with KDE or Konsole.  It's all about the `ls` program.  You'll see the same colors in gnome or even if you run a non-X Windows login session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get that information from [man ls](http://ss64.com/bash/ls.html) and following the link down the page to [ls environment variables](http://ss64.com/bash/lsenv.html).

Colors are controlled by the **LSCOLORS** environment variable. From the documentation above:

```
 LSCOLORS        The value of this variable describes what color to use
         for which attribute when colors are enabled with
         CLICOLOR.  This string is a concatenation of pairs of the
         format fb, where f is the foreground color and b is the
         background color.

         The color designators are as follows:

           a     black
           b     red
           c     green
           d     brown
           e     blue
           f     magenta
           g     cyan
           h     light grey
           A     bold black, usually shows up as dark grey
           B     bold red
           C     bold green
           D     bold brown, usually shows up as yellow
           E     bold blue
           F     bold magenta
           G     bold cyan
           H     bold light grey; looks like bright white
           x     default foreground or background

         Note that the above are standard ANSI colors.  The actual
         display may differ depending on the color capabilities of
         the terminal in use.

         The order of the attributes are as follows:

           1.   directory
           2.   symbolic link
           3.   socket
           4.   pipe
           5.   executable
           6.   block special
           7.   character special
           8.   executable with setuid bit set
           9.   executable with setgid bit set
           10.  directory writable to others, with sticky bit
           11.  directory writable to others, without sticky
            bit

         The default is "exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad", i.e. blue fore-
         ground and default background for regular directories,
         black foreground and red background for setuid executa-
         bles, etc.
```